# How to perform hive moveTask in parallel?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running a insert overwrite query on an external table which is partitioned (192 partitions).

On doing explain I see there are mainly two stage.

1. MR stage (8 mappers and 10 reducers)
2. Move Stage

MR stage is completing in 15-20 mins.

Move stage is taking about **3hours**.

On looking further I found, reducers are writing to a temporary location then in move stage it's moved to target location. Move from temp to target is happening sequentially. And since I have 192 partitions and 10 reducers. It's taking 3 hours to move all the files.

Is there a way to do move in parallel?

Hive Version: 1.2.1

Comment: This sounds strange, since moving files is a **metadata** operation.

Comment: It looks like it is still work in progress: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14129